# Исчезает операционная система

Tags: linux, windows, администрирование

У меня была `Windows 10` на ноутбуке, решила установить `Linux`. Сделала загрузочную флешку, всё хорошо установилось.

После первого перезапуска всё было окей, после второго ОС исчезла. Переустанавливала несколько раз, она всё время исчезала.

Думала, что это что-то с `Linux` и решила поставить `Windows 10` назад. Установила (всё прошло успешно, я это делаю не впервые, поэтому уверена, что всё сделала правильно), но после перезапуска она также исчезла. В `BIOS` её нет, при включении ноутбука пишет, что не найдена ОС и нужно нажать <kbd>Сtrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd>  для перезапуска.

Подскажите, как решить эту проблему?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106681/discussion-on-question-by-xal---).